# MariaDB Update table IF x null then update x else update y

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm working on a short term project at work. I need to do a script for bulking users from a table.
Anyway, I don't know how to write my request in a good way, here is what i want to do:

```
UPDATE table SET (IF date_fbulk IS NULL, date_fbulk = NOW(), date_lbulk = NOW())
```

I tried many different ways to do it but I can't succeed, it keeps telling my i have syntax error.

Here is the full request:

```
UPDATE enterprise.gen
SET
  bu_id = (SELECT MAX(b_id) FROM enterprise.bulk),
  IF(date_fbulk IS NULL, date_fbulk = NOW(), date_lbulk = NOW())
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Maybe you guys will have an idea on how solving this.
Thanks for reading

Comment: what syntax error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(date_fbulk IS NULL, date_fbulk = NOW(), date_lbulk = NOW()) ORDER BY RAND() L' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
IF(date_fbulk IS NULL, date_fbulk = NOW(), date_lbulk = NOW())
```

Try to write:

```
date_fbulk = COALESCE(date_fbulk, NOW()),
date_lbulk = IF(date_fbulk IS NOT NULL, NOW(), date_lbulk)
```

- `COALESCE(date_fbulk, NOW())` will return `date_fbulk` if it's not null, otherwise, it will return `NOW()`.

---

Full query:

```
UPDATE enterprise.gen
SET
  bu_id = (SELECT MAX(b_id) FROM enterprise.bulk),
  date_fbulk = COALESCE(date_fbulk, NOW()),
  date_lbulk = IF(date_fbulk IS NOT NULL, NOW(), date_lbulk)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```